# Is this proof of the Lah Numbers Polynomial Identity With Induction on $n$ correct?

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

The Lah numbers satisfy the following rising-falling factorials relation

\begin{equation}
x^{\overline{n}} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} L(n, k) x^{\underline{k}}, 
\end{equation}

where $x^{\overline{n}}$= $x(x+1)\times ... \times (x+n-1)$ and $x^{\underline{n}}$ = $x(x-1) \times ... \times (x-n+1)$.

What would be the proof of this identity using induction on $n$ with the following recurrence relation

$L(n, k) = L(n-1, k-1) + (n+k-1) L(n-1, k)$?

This is what I tried:
\begin{equation}
x^{\overline{n}} \\ =x^{\overline{n-1}} (x+n+k-1) \\
= \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} L(n-1, k) x^{\underline{k}} \right)  (x+n+k-1) \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{n} L(n-1, k) x^{\underline{k+1}} + (n+k-1) \sum_{k=0}^{n} L(n-1, k) x^{\underline{k}} \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{n} L(n-1, k-1) x^{\underline{k}} + \sum_{k=0}^{n} (n+k-1) L(n-1, k) x^{\underline{k}}  \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left( L(n-1, k-1) x^{\underline{k}} + (n+k-1) L(n-1, k) \right) x^{\underline{k}} \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{n} L(n, k) x^{\underline{k}},
\end{equation}

but I do not think that the proof is correct. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: what have you tried? try using the recursion for rising and falling factorials.

Comment: @Phicar I added what I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is wrong because, as I see it, you tried to force the recursion when you do $$x^{\overline{n}} = x^{\overline{n-1}}(x+n+k-1),$$
that is **not true**, but you can do this:

$$x^{\overline{n}} = x^{\overline{n-1}}(x+n-1)=x^{\overline{n-1}}((x\color{red}{-k})+(n\color{red}{+k}-1)).$$
Now, when you distribute you will get
$$\sum _{k = 0}^{n-1}{L(n-1,k)(x-k)x^{\underline{k}}}+\sum _{k = 0}^{n-1}{L(n-1,k)(n+k-1)x^{\underline{k}}}.$$
Notice that $(x-k)x^{\underline{k}}=x^{\underline{k+1}}$ and you would be done.

**Ps.** Why is the \underline so ugly?

Comment: Thank you very much. I do not know why is \underline ugly, I use x^{\underline{n}}. Could you please provide the whole proof? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @User303131 What do you mean the whole proof? What is not clear?

Comment: So this is the correct proof? \begin{equation}
x^{\overline{n}} \\ =x^{\overline{n-1}} ((x-k)+(n+k-1)) \\
= \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} L(n-1, k) x^{\underline{k}} \right)  ((x-k)+(n+k-1)) \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} L(n-1, k) (x-k) x^{\underline{k}} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} L(n-1, k) (n+k-1) x^{\underline{k}} \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} L(n-1, k-1) x^{\underline{k+1}} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (n+k-1) L(n-1, k) x^{\underline{k}}  \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( L(n-1, k-1) x^{\underline{k}} + (n+k-1) L(n-1, k) \right) x^{\underline{k}} \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{n} L(n, k) x^{\underline{k}},
\end{equation}

Comment: @User303131 Yes! That is correct. Well done.

Comment: Happy to hear that-thank you very much!